# How do I preserve my colorscheme when I sudo to root?

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme, sudo

I have many users who sudo to root to edit certain files. How can I allow each of them to use their own ~/.vimrc file once they have sudo'd to root? In other words. they each want to use their own color scheme, even though they are acting as root. Is there a way to have VIM use the original user's .vimrc file (before sudo)?

Comment: Teach them about `sudo -e`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original user is stored in the `SUDO_USER` environment variable. So your root's vimrc you could do something along the lines of:

```
if file_readable('/home/' . $SUDO_USER . '/.vimrc')
    source '/home/' . $SUDO_USER . '/.vimrc'
elseif file_readable('/home/' . $SUDO_USER. '/.vim/vimrc')
    source  $'/home/' . $SUDO_USER. '/.vim/vimrc'
endif
```

As mentioned in the comments, your users can also use `sudoedit` (aka. `sudo -e`). This will copy the file to a temporary location, `chown` it to the current user, and run `EDITOR` for it as the currently logged in user, and after `EDITOR` is finished, the temporary file is moved back to the original. This was designed to solve exactly this problem ;-)

Comment: Does this set the runtime path to include `/home/$SUDO_USER/.vim`?